# Connect to mailbox using modern authentication using c# console

Tags: c#, console-application

Currently I am using basic auth, now I'll have to use modern authentication for this project.

Basic authentication code and it was working fine

```
exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Mail_box_username","Mail_box_password"); 
exchange.Url = new Uri("exchangeServer");
exchange.Url.Host;
```

Now Microsoft will disable the basic auth from 1st Oct.

Comment: What do you mean by `modern authentication`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: I think you're talking about OAuth. You need to "register" your application with your Microsoft Account. This will generate a string token that you can use in your application to connect. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

Comment: @Chetan - Access the mailbox by using secret keys and app ID and tenentID.

Comment: @SlackGroverglow - That I have done already and I got the client ID and secret keys

Comment: I tried to get help from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth#code-samples   but still not able to figure out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chetan - Modern auth means, access the mailbox by using AppID, Secret key and tenant ID instead of password.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN - I am using below code to access the mailbox by using key values var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(["appId"])
                .WithClientSecret(["clientSecret"])
                .WithTenantId(["tenantId"])
                .Build();
            var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };
            try
            {
                **var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();** Not able fetch the token value to proceed further